# Canvas not drawing when page is returned with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, canvas

I am working on a website with AJAX returning search results. Everything is working correctly, however, I have a Canvas that I am defining for each of the results, and it is not being drawn at all. If I hard code the Canvas and Script to draw, it works, however, when I move it to the PHP file that is running the query, it just shows up as a blank Canvas.

Here is my AJAX call, just in case that might have an effect on the outcome:

```
function funSearch(val)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    
    url = "search.php?search=" + val;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And this is the code I am trying to run (values ending with a # are echoed by the PHP script from a mySQL database):

```
<canvas id='statsID#'></canvas>";
<script>funStats(statsID#, HP#, ATT#, SPA#, DEF#, SPD#, SPE#);</script>";
```

And this is the Javascript I use to draw, although I highly doubt this is the issue as when I card code the aforementioned canvas/script text, it works properly:

```
function funStats(id, hp, att, spa, def, spd, spe)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    
    var hpContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var attContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var spaContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var defContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var spdContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var speContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    canvas.width = 60;
    canvas.height = 60;
    
    var x = canvas.width / 2;
    var y = canvas.height / 2;
    
    var hpRadius = 28;
    var attRadius = 24;
    var spaRadius = 20;
    var defRadius = 16;
    var spdRadius = 12;
    var speRadius = 8;
    
    var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
    
    var hpEndAngle = ((hp / (256 / 2)) + 1.5) * Math.PI;
    var attEndAngle = ((att / (256 / 2)) + 1.5) * Math.PI;
    var spaEndAngle = ((spa / (256 / 2)) + 1.5) * Math.PI;
    var defEndAngle = ((def / (256 / 2)) + 1.5) * Math.PI;
    var spdEndAngle = ((spd / (256 / 2)) + 1.5) * Math.PI;
    var speEndAngle = ((spe / (256 / 2)) + 1.5) * Math.PI;
    
    hpContext.beginPath();
    hpContext.arc(x, y, hpRadius, startAngle, hpEndAngle, false);
    hpContext.lineWidth = 2;
    hpContext.strokeStyle = '#42af4f';
    hpContext.stroke();
    
    attContext.beginPath();
    attContext.arc(x, y, attRadius, startAngle, attEndAngle, false);
    attContext.lineWidth = 2;
    attContext.strokeStyle = '#d4bb49';
    attContext.stroke();
    
    spaContext.beginPath();
    spaContext.arc(x, y, spaRadius, startAngle, spaEndAngle, false);
    spaContext.lineWidth = 2;
    spaContext.strokeStyle = '#4a95ca';
    spaContext.stroke();
    
    defContext.beginPath();
    defContext.arc(x, y, defRadius, startAngle, defEndAngle, false);
    defContext.lineWidth = 2;
    defContext.strokeStyle = '#cc6a14';
    defContext.stroke();
    
    spdContext.beginPath();
    spdContext.arc(x, y, spdRadius, startAngle, spdEndAngle, false);
    spdContext.lineWidth = 2;
    spdContext.strokeStyle = '#8e55d3';
    spdContext.stroke();
    
    speContext.beginPath();
    speContext.arc(x, y, speRadius, startAngle, speEndAngle, false);
    speContext.lineWidth = 2;
    speContext.strokeStyle = '#ce58b0';
    speContext.stroke();
}
```

I have moved it to being hardcoded (worked), but once I move it into the AJAX PHP, it does not work. Also tried moving the script to be on the main page, the AJAX page, and an external document with including it with a Script tag. No changes.

Comment: But your ajax call is simply populating `'results'` element with the results - where do you call the `funStats` function?

Comment: What format of data is returned by `search.php` - formatted HTML, JSON, string? How do you set the values for the parameters used by `funStats`?

Answer (score 0):

change your function to create a canvas object for said drawing

like

```js
function funStats(id, hp, att, spa, def, spd, spe)
{
    // Create the canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // Set the canvas size
    canvas.width = 60;
    canvas.height = 60;
    // append the canvas to the document
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    /* All Other code here*/
}
```

Comment: you wont need the `id` variable... but kept it for sake of confusion